# How to deduct quantity from stock C# sql

Tags: c#, sql

Once the product is bought it should reduce from stock quantity

```
double qun;

qun = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value) - Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);

sqlconnection = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString);
sqlcommand = new SqlCeCommand();
sqlconnection.Open();
sqlcommand.Connection = sqlconnection;
sqlcommand.CommandText = (@"UPDATE ItemStock_Info SET Quantity =@qun WHERE [Item_Number]='"+ textBox1.Text +"'");
sqlcommand.Parameters.Add("@qun", qun);

sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlconnection.Close();
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable `qun` is the quantity sold then you should subtract it from the value in the database table not simply assign that value back overwriting your stock value

```
   @"UPDATE ItemStock_Info 
     SET Quantity = Quantity - @qun 
     WHERE ...  "
```

A note to you. Why use a parameter for the quantity and not for the where condition? This should be avoided at all costs and parameters should be added in a different way

```
sqlcommand.CommandText = (@"UPDATE ItemStock_Info 
                          SET Quantity = Quantity - @qun 
                          WHERE [Item_Number]=@num";
sqlcommand.Parameters.Add("@qun", SqlDbType.Float).Value = qun;
sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@num", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I should add a warning here. I guess that you don't want to subtract the quantity sold if this change your Quantity value to a level below zero. Being this a SQL Server CE database, it is probably safe to assume that none could change the `Quantity` value behind your back and you have already tested this condition before the subtract operation, but in a multiuser environment I suggest you to use a database that has better support for concurrency on these fields.